# Gradle: Inject plugins to subprojects

Tags: gradle

I came across [gradle plugin](https://github.com/esycat/gradle-config-plugin) to help me to deal with dotted property names. It works fine in single project when used like this:

```
apply plugin: 'config'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.esyfur:gradle-config-plugin:0.4.+'
    }
}

task printProps() {
    println(config.grafana.url)
}
```

However, I want to use this plugin in multiple projects (multi-module) and would like idealy not to repeat such initialization in every project but rather inject it somehow to have it more manageable.

I have failed to find out how to do it or if it can be done. I tried e.g. in parent build.gradle use this:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'config'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.esyfur:gradle-config-plugin:0.4.+'
    }
}
```

but it does not work. Gradle complains that it can not find property 'config' on task.

### Update

After Peter's comment I started wondering around and creating an example project from the scratch and incrementally get it closer to my 'real project'. I was not completely precise in describing my setup. In settings.gradle I use

```
rootProject.children.each { project ->
    project.buildFileName = "${project.name}.gradle"
}
```

which causes this problem. Everything works fine When switched back to build.gradle names.

Comment: It works exactly like you showed. Perhaps try with a different Gradle version (I think one version had a regression).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I use gradle wrapper 2.0. But you comment made me thinking and doing some more trials ... see updated question.

Comment: Update 1 is not how you'd normally add plugins to the buildscript classpath. Update 2 is very weird. Perhaps try with 1.12 or 2.1 nightly.

Comment: I will delete update 1 to not to confuse anyone else. As for update 2, I observe error with 1.10, 2.0, 2.2 nightly. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Example project is here: https://github.com/jojovilco/plugin-inject-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `settings.gradle` doesn't configure `rootProject.buildFileName` to match the non-standard filename used for the build script. Therefore the build script doesn't get evaluated, and its `buildscript` block never takes effect.